# Separate same values in list of list - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a list

`l=[('a', 120), ('b', 2039), ('b', 0), ('c', 98), ('a', 34), ('a', 0), ('h', 46), ('c', 78)]`

I want to convert this list like this -

```
l=[
       [('a', 120), ('a', 34), ('a', 0)], 
       [('b', 2039), ('b', 0)],
       [('c', 98), ('c', 78)], 
       [('h', 46)],
   ]
```

How to achieve this conversion in python list in less time,
thanks

Comment: what does it mean by less time?

Comment: @shivankgtm, less time means, the conversion will be fastly, i done the conversion with few for loops - which takes more time, if the list has many elements

Comment: It would help if you show the code you've written that's too slow

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this does it in "less time" because there are no comparative timing data. Here are two versions. One that uses *defaultdict* from the *collections* module and one that utilises a dictionary's built-in functionality.

In case you're tempted to use *defaultdict*, note that it's marginally slower than the alternative.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from timeit import timeit

l = [('a', 120), ('b', 2039), ('b', 0), ('c', 98),
     ('a', 34), ('a', 0), ('h', 46), ('c', 78)]

def func_1(l):
    d = {}
    for k, v in l:
        d.setdefault(k, []).append((k, v))
    return list(d.values())

def func_2(l):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in l:
        d[k].append((k, v))
    return list(d.values())

for func in func_1, func_2:
    print(func.__name__, timeit(lambda: func(l)))
```

**Output:**

```
func_1 1.1978088119999484
func_2 1.3840169149998474
```

Comment: or just use `collection.defaultdict` directly...

Comment: @Julien There's no such thing. If you mean *defaultdict* from *collections* then yes, I could have used that but where's the advantage?

Comment: just keeps the code (a little) simpler by reusing existing libraries rather than recoding them...

Comment: @Julien There's no recoding here. *setdefault* is a built-in feature of dictionaries and by excluding an import and, if you insist on being pedantic, this is likely to be faster for a one-time run than if an import was included. However, if my suggested answer fails to might your obviously high standards I'll be happy to delete it

Comment: It doesn't fail anything, it's perfectly valid, I was just pointing OP to another very similar and slightly more concise alternative.

Comment: @Julien I have edited my answer for additional clarity bearing in mind the OP's obvious concern with performance

Answer (score 1):

There are probably better ways but this is what I came up with is vanilla.

```
l=[('a', 120), ('b', 2039), ('b', 0), ('c', 98), ('a', 34), ('a', 0), ('h', 46), ('c', 78)]

tmp_l = {}
for key,value in l:
  if tmp_l.get(key) is not None:
    tmp_l[key].append(value)
    continue

  tmp_l[key]=[value]

result = []
for key, value in tmp_l.items():
  result.append([(key, item) for item in value])

print(result)
```

Comment: You are essentially recoding existing `collections.defautdict` from scratch here...

Comment: ya, I was unaware of that feature, plus sometimes it's nice to not use libraries. I enjoy them as much as the next person, but sometimes its nice to dive into the process.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it thusly if you are simply looking to nest comprehensions:

```
data = [('a', 120), ('b', 2039), ('b', 0), ('c', 98), ('a', 34), ('a', 0), ('h', 46), ('c', 78)]

print( sorted( [entry for entry in data if entry[0] == label] for label in set([label for (label, _) in data]) ) )
```

Be aware that if this is just a homework assignment, you are only hurting yourself by failing both to explore the language and to practice your skills in problem solving.

Comment: This is very neat but also very slow

Answer (score 1):

the alternative is using groupby, but it is certainly slower than [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73412041/18344512) solution:

```
from itertools import groupby

[list(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(l),lambda x: x[0])]

>>> out
'''
[[('a', 0), ('a', 34), ('a', 120)],
 [('b', 0), ('b', 2039)],
 [('c', 78), ('c', 98)],
 [('h', 46)]]
```

and if you're looking for efficiency it might makes sence to transform your data into dict like this `{'a': [120, 34, 0], 'b': [2039, 0], 'c': [98, 78], 'h': [46]}`

and for a realy large dataset `pandas` could be very handy